# Android create a layout for calendar event with freeze header and column

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, calendar, android-tablelayout

I have a layout need to implement as the image attach.

[image]

Display events group by days and user. I also found some libs such as TableFixHeaders, Android-Week-View

But it seems not to meet my requirement and request a lot of time to study and modify.

**Is there any other library or I have to work from scratch?**

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For that you can use **https://github.com/alamkanak/Android-Week-View**

[image]

**Features**

> Week view calendar
>
> Day view calendar
>
> Custom styling
>
> **Horizontal and vertical scrolling**
>
> Infinite horizontal scrolling

**Grab via gradle**

```
compile 'com.github.alamkanak:android-week-view:1.2.6'
```

Comment: Okay that is more better you got what you wanted. Good work.

Comment: Hi @user3007780, can you please help me with my problem?Sorry that I copied your image :) [My question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40060347/android-journal-with-events-for-peson-time)

Comment: Hi @user1358444 have you found any solution for this?

Comment: Hi @AbidKhan How to scroll the week by week in alamkanak:android SDK? If any idea?